# Javascript calculation with 2 variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with my form calculating.

This is my javascript:

```
function kembali()

var total=document.getElementById('total1').value;
var bayar=document.getElementById('bayar1').value;
document.getElementById('kembalian1').value=bayar*total;
```

And this is my html
:

```
<form><table><tr>
    <td>Total</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="total" id="total1" value="50000"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Bayar</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="bayar" id="bayar1" onkeyup="kembali()" autocomplete="off"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Kembalian</td>
    <td>:</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="kembalian" id="kembalian1"/></td>
</tr></table></form>
```

I use this code to jsfiddle.net and didn't work. How to fix this? Can you help me? Thank you.

[Here's the example](https://jsfiddle.net/92p7v2vm/)

Comment: see updated fiddle here   https://jsfiddle.net/92p7v2vm/1/   . wrap your function on head  tag

Comment: That is not a valid function...

Comment: just change your javascript to `No Wrap in Head` it will work. https://jsfiddle.net/92p7v2vm/2/

Comment: In your fiddle under "Frameworks &Extensions" change the drop down value from "onLoad" to "No Wrap-in<head>"

Answer (score 2):

you need to select option `onLoad`  to  `No Wrap in head` from drop down under `Frameworks & Extensions`.

update [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/92p7v2vm/1/)

[jsfiddle documentation](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#frameworks-and-extensions)

Second drop-down is about the `Code Wrap` with default setting to `onLoad`.

**There are 4 options to choose:**

**onLoad:**

wrap the code so it will run in onLoad window event

**onDomReady:**

wrap the code so it will run in onDomReady window event

**no wrap - in `<head>`:**

do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in `<head>` section

**no wrap - in `<body>`:**

do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in `<body>` section

Comment: You missed the head and body in no wrap - in part,                                     no wrap - in <head>: do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in <head> section                                                                                                       no wrap - in <body>: do not wrap the JavaScript code, place it in <body> section         Can you edit your answer like this ?

Comment: @ThirumalSakthivel check updated answer .. due to `<>` tag is hide in answer .. its updated now  .. thank you